# How to split one table into multiple tables with different columns (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one single table with 25 columns and I want to split it into 3 or 4 tables with a smaller column count. Below is a simplified example as a reference:

This is the big table

| supplier | brand | sku | product_class | size | sales | trans_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| supplier_1 | brand_1 | sku_1 | class_1 | 3.5 | 100 | 1 |
| supplier_1 | brand_2 | sku_2 | class_1 | 3.5 | 200 | 2 |

I need something like this:

product_info

| sku | product_class | size | trans_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sku_1 | class_1 | 3.5 | 1 |
| sku_2 | class_1 | 3.5 | 2 |

product_sales

| supplier | brand | sales | trans_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| supplier_1 | brand_1 | 100 | 1 |
| supplier_1 | brand_2 | 200 | 2 |

In this case, trans_id from the product_info table would be my PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag, since you said in the question that you are using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can split tables like Products, Brands, Carts. Then connect them using foreign keys.

**Products** table can have the column **company_id** that refers to its company.

The carts table holds users' purchases information and has columns such as **product_id** and **user_id**.

It's also better to have a **CartProducts** table that one shipment may contain multiple products.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use views (i.e. logical tables) for the purpose. Lightweight and efficient. Here is an illustration:

```sql
create or replace view product_info as
 select trans_id, sku, product_class, size 
 from the_big_table;

create or replace view product_sales as
 select trans_id, supplier, brand, sales 
 from the_big_table;

-- more view definitions here
```

Joining these views would be trivial and with no overhead:

```sql
select ... 
 from product_info join product_sales using (trans_id);
```